# Maven built swf(flex project) throwing errors at application start

Tags: apache-flex, maven

I'm getting the following error at the start of my application:

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable mx.messaging.config::ConfigMap is not defined.

at _ABC_FlexInit$/init()

```
      at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::kickOff()

      at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()

      at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()

      at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()

      at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()

      at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()

      at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I have gone through a lot of posts on various forums. Most of them say that this error usually occurs in cases like:

```
not declaring classes as 'public'
trying to refer something that isn't there
syntax error
```

When i run my application, it actually runs just fine. When i try to run the swf that is generated from maven install on my application, that is when this error occurs. So i can safely say that the above mentioned cases are not the reason for this error. So why is my maven built swf throwing this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing that class instance at runtime.  My guess would be that your Maven configuration assumes that this class (which I think is in rpc.swc under your FLEX_HOME/frameworks/lib/ directory) will be loaded as an RSL - but it cannot be found.  You need to double check your Maven configuration and find out how you are including all elements of the framework and that you are including all necessary RSL's with your application when you deploy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,

I have included the dependency for rpc.swc in my pom.xml:

     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
       <artifactId>rpc</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.0.16076</version>
       <type>swc</type>
       <scope>external</scope>
    </dependency>



Shall i share my pom.xml file for clarity????

Comment: could you please share your email, so i can send you my pom.xml file?